# How to deal with small AND unbalanced datasets for machine learning classification problems

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-analysis

I am dealing with a very challenging classification problem where I have three problems: A small dataset (about 800 samples), unbalanced dataset (4 classes where 1 - 600 samples, 2/3/4 - 50 samples each) and missing data in one of the features.

Some things that I have been considering:

- Generate synthetic data, for example using SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique).
- Turn the classification into a binary classification between the minority and majority.
- Combine different classifiers giving more weight on negative samples (in case I turn into a binary classifier).
- Cost sensitive learning by applying specific weights in the cost function (kinda similar to the previous, but using all 4 classes).

I intend to use as classifiers Naive Bayes, SVM, Random Forests and Neural Networks and 2 fold cross validation. Later I might move to 5 to 10 folds.

Some characteristics of the features:

- 5 continuous, where 3 of them are just different properties based on graph location (min, max and distribution) and some of them have very low variance and repeated data
- 2 binary features where one of them have missing data.

Snippet of the data:

```
Y   X1  X2_min  X2_max  X2_distribution X3  X4  X5
3   6   1       11      3.3058739       0   1   1
3   662 1       11      1.7779095       1   15  1
1   6   1       7       3.060274        0   1   1
3   8   1       6       2.9697127       0   1   1
3   82  1       14      3.0341356       0   1   1
2   39  1       7       4.2189913       0   1   1
4   1   3       14      4.6185904           1   1
```

I would appreciate very much any second thought.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend either going for more weight or duplicating the data belonging to the smaller class. One way would be to add random noise to the instances of the smaller class while duplicating it. The variance of the noise can be estimated from the variance of the features within each class.

Answer (score 1):

A small dataset isnt a problem if they are the most representative examples (e.g., currently there are advances being made where even deep learning techniques are being applied to small datasets). How can you tell if your data set is representative? It requires proper sampling techniques such as stratified sampling instead of say, random sampling.

To tackle unbalanced datasets, there are various techniques: undersampling (not applicable in your case because of a small dataset), oversampling (can work, but there is a risk of model overfitting), and cost-sensitive learning (see the Vowpal Wabbit toolkit for an implementation)